# Opening a FiST Cryptfs dir from 2002

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, encryption, cryptography

I have a dir from 2002 encrypted with [CryptFS](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix01/freenix01/full_papers/cattaneo/cattaneo_html/node5.html) which uses FiST.

In theory I can probably install a virtual machine running a GNU/Linux distribution from 2002, compile FiST and CryptFS - if I can find the source.

But is there an easier way I can open that dir that I can use on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this far:

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.filesystems.org/pub/fistgen/fistgen-0.2.1.tar.gz
$ tar xvzf fistgen-0.2.1.tar.gz
$ ./configure 
$ make
$ ./fistgen cryptfs/cryptfs.fist
$ cd out/Linux-2.4/cryptfs/
$ make
```

But the last compile fails (on Centos 3):

```
In file included from /usr/include/linux/signal.h:4,
                 from /usr/include/linux/sched.h:25,
                 from fist.h:29,
                 from fist_cryptfs.c:13:
/usr/include/asm/signal.h:107: syntax error before "sigset_t"
/usr/include/asm/signal.h:110: syntax error before '}' token
```